# How can I enforce lifetimes for a struct that contains a raw pointer?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

> **Editor's note:** This code no longer compiles in Rust 1.0 with the error `` parameter `'a` is never used ``. The reason for this error is exactly because of the problem demonstrated below, so the (updated) solution remains applicable.

```
extern crate core;
use core::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

struct MutPtr<'a, T> {
    ptr: *mut T,
}
impl<'a, T> MutPtr<'a, T> {
    fn new<'b>(value: &'b mut T) -> MutPtr<'b, T> {
        MutPtr { ptr: value }
    }
}
impl<'a, T> Deref for MutPtr<'a, T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        unsafe { &(*self.ptr) }
    }
}
impl<'a, T> DerefMut for MutPtr<'a, T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        unsafe { &mut (*self.ptr) }
    }
}
struct Bar {
    v: i32,
}

fn err<'a>() -> MutPtr<'a, Bar> {
    let mut b = Bar { v: 42 };
    MutPtr::new(&mut b) // Shouldn't this throw an error?
}

fn main() {
    let mut b = Bar { v: 42 };
    let mut ptr_b = MutPtr::new(&mut b);
    let mut ptr_b1 = MutPtr::new(&mut b);

    ptr_b.v = 10;
    println!("{}", b.v);
    ptr_b1.v = 21;
    println!("{}", b.v);
}
```

This code block is causing some confusion:

```
fn err<'a>() -> MutPtr<'a, Bar> {
    let mut b = Bar { v: 42 };
    MutPtr::new(&mut b) // Shouldn't this throw an error?
}
```

Why does this compile?

When I call

```
MutPtr::new(&mut b)
```

Shouldn't it have the lifetime of `b`? I expected a compile error because the lifetime `'a` is longer than the lifetime of `MutPtr<'b, Bar>`.

Comment: Are you intentionally storing the value as `*mut T` instead of `&'a mut T`?

Comment: @Dogbert yes because I want multiple mutable pointers in the same scope.(For experimentation only)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `core::marker::PhantomData` (also available in `std::marker::PhantomData`).
What happens is that the compiler does not assign any lifetime to a pointer variable, so the compiler doesn't know how to constrain the lifetime of the structure.

The way to do it is to add a marker `PhantomData<&'a ()>` to your structure, which tells the compiler the lifetime of the entire structure may not outlive `'a` (in effect, pretending that `MutPtr<'a, T>` has a `&'a ()` field in it, even though it does not).

So in the end your struct should look like this:

```
struct MutPtr<'a, T> {
    ptr: *mut T,
    _covariant: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

impl<'a, T> MutPtr<'a, T> {
    fn new(value: &'a mut T) -> MutPtr<'a, T> {
        MutPtr {
            ptr: value,
            _covariant: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
```

With this you get the expected error `b does not live long enough`.

Comment: I have done the same thing a few minutes ago. The problem with this is that `b.v` won't work anymore once I have done `MutPtr::new(&mut b)`. I assume `ContravariantLifetime` saves that a variable was mutably borrowed? The error is `cannot use b.v because it was mutably borrowed`

Comment: I guess the issue is because what you are trying to do (creating two mutable references to the same content) is explicitly marked as [undefined behaviour](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/unsafe.html#references). Thus, maybe there is no way for you to provide a safe interface implementing this kind of behaviour, or at least I don't know it.

Comment: @MaikKlein: You should take a look at [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), which lets you, for example, have many immutable references to a `RefCell` from which you can obtain a mutable reference to the interior, as long as there is only one active mutable borrow at a time.

Comment: I want to try ContravariantLifetime? Where can I find it? Do I need to use unstable rust with a feature enabled? Do I need to use a library? `use std::marker::ContravariantLifetime;` errors with `no `ContravariantLifetime` in `marker`.

Comment: `ContravariantLifetime` was replaced by `std::marker::PhantomData` some time ago.